# Как скачать и запустить NuGet CLI в скрипте gitlab ci/cd?

Tags: gitlab-ci, nuget

Пыталась скачать через curl, wget и на разных образах: убунту, докер.. Качать-то, качает вроде как, но не дает запустить: то пермиссий нет, то ошибка с непонятными символами.

Comment: ну в целом алгоритм такой
Качаем
curl -o nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
даем разрешения - chmod +x nuget.exe
запускаем - ./nuget.exe help

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov я так и делала, но по какой-то причине именно в гитлабе он бросает непонятную ошибку. Я пробовала на WSL Ubuntu сделать так - у меня всё отлично заработало. А Вы на каком имедже предлагаете сделать?

Comment: так же про убунту

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov так ведь там не предустановлен керл. А установка требует нажать Y. Как этот момент в скрипте отследить?

Comment: sudo apt-get install -y curl